# Inserting data into cassandra using Aquiles

Tags: c#, cassandra, aquiles

I got a sample code from net for inserting:

1. In the line below, should `"Cassandra1"` be placed in `web.config`? If yes as what?

   ```
   ICluster cluster = AquilesHelper.RetrieveCluster("Cassandra1");
   ```
2. In the code below, what is `CassandraClient`? Is it a class? What should be inside the `CassandraClient` class?

   ```
   cluster.Execute(new ExecutionBlock(delegate(CassandraClient client)
   {
     client.insert(key, columnParent, column, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
   }), keyspace);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question can be found [here](http://aquiles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Aquiles.Configuration&referringTitle=Documentation).

A quick read of the source code reveals this type alias in DefaultClient.cs:

```
using CassandraClient = Apache.Cassandra.Cassandra.Client;
```

So `CassandraClient` is an instance of `Apache.Cassandra.Cassandra.Client`, which is the client generated by the Thrift C# code generator.